# set UIPickerView relative to screen

Tags: ios, ipad

I currently have a UIPickerView that is in a view hidden offscreen, and when a button is pressed, the PickerView animates in (from the bottom, animates up). When the user is done with the pickerview, they click the "done" button in the view, and the view animates offscreen. This all works flawlessly, except for when the screen is in landscape orientation. The coordinates are different than when the device is in portrait. Is there a way to make this work for either orientation?

Pictures of my situation:

Pickerview:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn6kd.png]

Pickerview on rotate:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFGq1.png]

As you can see when rotated, the pickerview isn't even visible.

Comment: Please show the code where you are positioning the view.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a percentage rather than fixed pixels. Eg self.view.frame.size.height * 0.5 as opposed to hardcoding 384

Either that or you could just use a modal view?

Comment: This solved it. Thanks, the "self.view.frame.size.height" is what I was looking for.